# Enterprise Architect - giva a Model a default Tagged value when dragged/dropped as Hyperlink

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

i use extensively Enterprise Architect and have a library of several packages/models

Now, i use to add a modell itsself with drag and drop in a Diagram. 
I need to assign a disctinct TaggedValue each time.

is it possible to add this model (in my example) **parameterassignment in ip-step**
a default Tagged Value???

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I have understood your question correctly, if so...

You can do this via Enterprise Architect's scripting capabilities after the fact. Once you have created all your diagram hyperlinks, select them on the screen then run the following:

```
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-JScript

/*
 * Script Name: Add tagged values to select diagram items
 * Author: TomO
 * Purpose: To add tagged values to selected diagram items
 * Date: 31st August 2012
 */

function main()
{
    var diagram as EA.Diagram

diagram = GetCurrentDiagram();

for ( i = 0; i < diagram.SelectedObjects.Count; i ++ )
{
var object as EA.DiagramObject;
var element as EA.Element;
var tag as EA.TaggedValue;

object = diagram.SelectedObjects.GetAt(i);
element = GetElementByID(object.ElementID);

tag = element.TaggedValues.AddNew("email", "");
tag.Value = "";
tag.Update();
}


}

main();
```

You would want to change the line:

tag = element.TaggedValue.AddNew("ENTER THE DEFAULT NAME OF YOUR TAGGED VALUE", "ENTER IN THE DEFAULT VALUE FOR THE TAGGED VALUE");

I hope this helps!

TomO

Comment: Hi TomO, thank you for your answer. This is intresting, but not that does not solve my problem. The "Hyperlink" resp. the Model i drop in the Workspace should already hat a default taggedvalue. With your code i can add one tagged value with its value to existing "hyperlinks" if new or old :-). thank you in Advance

Comment: Hey Arphex, I am not sure you are going to be able to get exactly what you are after because you are unable to profile hyperlinks. Profiling is where you would normally add default tagged values to model elements. As a hyperlink is a diagram element not a model element this is not possible. It might be worth sending an email to the guys at sparx systems as a feature request. They are historically very good at listening to customer requests for Enterprise Architect. It might even be worth visiting the user forum on the sparx systems website and put the question to them? Hope this helps